# Multiple Insert Input data in mysql

Tags: php, html

I have some problem with multiple input $_POST into sql but I can't see the $_POST, here my code :

**Html Code:**

```html
<form action="inc/barangproses.php" method="post" class="modal-content form-horizontal" id="updateallform">
<input id="CPU0014" name="noresi[]" value="CPU0014" class="hidden" type="text">
<input id="CPU0017" name="noresi[]" value="CPU0017" class="hidden" type="text">
<input id="CPU0020" name="noresi[]" value="CPU0020" class="hidden" type="text">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="updateallbarang">Update</button>
</form>
```

**PHP Code:**

```html
 if (isset($_POST['updateallbarang'])) {
 $resi    = $_POST['noresi'];
 $idstatus  = '3';
 $sql = "";
 foreach($resi as $noresi ){
 $sql .= "INSERT INTO tracking(NORESI)
    VALUES ('$noresi');";
 $sql .= "INSERT INTO logkiriman(NORESI)
    VALUES ('$noresi');";
 $sql .= "UPDATE kiriman SET IDSTATUS = '$idstatus' WHERE NORESI = '$noresi';";
 }
 multiquery_db($sql);
 }
 else {
        header('location: ../barang.php?error='.base64_encode('Pilih kiriman terlebih dahulu.'));
  }
 }
```

**Config Code:**

```html
$db_host  = "localhost";
$db_user  = "root";
$db_password = "";
$db_name  = "db";
$dir    = "http://localhost/admin/";

$konek  = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

function multiquery_db($query){
  global $konek;
  $result = mysqli_multi_query($konek, $query);
  return $result;
  mysqli_free_result($konek);
  mysqli_close($konek);
  }
```

**Sql Result not show $noresi :**

```html
INSERT INTO tracking(NORESI) VALUES ('');
INSERT INTO logkiriman(NORESI) VALUES ('');
UPDATE kiriman SET IDSTATUS = '3' WHERE NORESI = '';
INSERT INTO tracking(NORESI) VALUES ('');
INSERT INTO logkiriman(NORESI) VALUES ('');
UPDATE kiriman SET IDSTATUS = '3' WHERE NORESI = '';
INSERT INTO tracking(NORESI) VALUES ('');
INSERT INTO logkiriman(NORESI) VALUES ('');
UPDATE kiriman SET IDSTATUS = '3' WHERE NORESI = '';
```

Please tell me where the wrong code ? I want to input multiple $_POST['noresi'] with multiple query into MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not in the foreach loop, execute each query and test this way first?

**Example**

```
var_dump($resi);
foreach($resi as $noresi ){     
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO tracking(NORESI)  VALUES ('$noresi')");
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO logkiriman(NORESI)                VALUES ('$noresi')"); 
mysqli_query("UPDATE kiriman SET IDSTATUS = '$idstatus' WHERE NORESI    = '$noresi'");
}
```

**EDIT**
The purpose of `var_dump` here is to echo the contents of the array to the screen, this way you can see if you have what you expect in `$resi`

Comment: Edited my orignal answer with an example of what I mean, sorry about formatting, I'm on mobile

Comment: I was try that code before, foreach($resi as $noresi ){    echo $noresi; } <=== I try this code too, but never show $noresi...how to fix this ?

Comment: Before the foreach loop have you tried a `var_dump($resi);` ?

Comment: not yet, could you recode again sir with var_dump example ?

Comment: Edited to show var_dump... Note it will probably show an error after the output as the script will try to modify headers after the script has echo'd something

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "CPU0014" [1]=> string(7) "CPU0017" [2]=> string(7) "CPU0020" }  <=== here the result sir

Comment: Are those the values you are expecting to see inserted into the database?

Comment: Yes sir, I want insert that values from multiple input and post that values into each row and each table database

Comment: I try again and the $noresi show in query, I think XAMP 3.2.2 have some error in index....thanks